# Centrar imagen con rectángulo sin modificar el display, sin utilizar posiciones absolutas y más

Tags: css, xhtml

La idea es llegar a este resultado, tiene que quedar completamente centrado y responsive, vertical y horizontalmente:

[idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLDrV.png).[image: idea]

Los requisitos son:

- No modificar el display.
- position: absolute; siempre, sin excepciones.
- No utilizar propiedades como background-position. La imagen tiene que ser un
- No utilizar transform.

[rojo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMNRI.png)

Muchas gracias.

Solución:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio de Posicionamiento</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    
  <div id="main-container">
    <img id="rojo" src="rojo.png" alt="Rojo">
    <div id="rectangulo">
      ABSOLUTO
    </div>
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#main-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  position: absolute;
}

#rojo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#rectangulo {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -275px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: "La imagen tiene que ser un ....."  ????

Comment: Puede ser una `<img>` en lugar de usar background-image?

Comment: Si, puede ser un <img>

Answer (score 0):

Con todas las restricciones creo que lo complicado es que sea responsivo tanto vertical y horizontalmente. Es decir que el contenido permanezca en el centro.

Creo que el truco está en buscar un ancho que se ajuste automaticamente, para eso puedes usar la función `min`, por ejemplo `min(100vh,100vw)` no dará el mínimo valor entre el alto y el ancho, entonces si queremos que el valor sea la mitad del mínimo valor hacemos `min(50vh,50vw)`, luego es cosa de usar este valor para ir calculando posiciones

Demo:

```css
#contenedor {
    position:absolute;
    width: min(50vh,50vw);
    height:  auto;
    top: calc(50% - min(50vh,50vw) / 2);
    left: calc(50% - min(50vh,50vw) / 2);
}

#rojo {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}

#azul {
  width:120%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height:40px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left:-10%;
  top: calc(min(50vh,50vw) / 2 - 20px);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMNRI.png" id="rojo"/>
  <div id="azul">
    ABSOLUTO
  </div>
</div>
```